# On-demand resources are not downloading for a specific device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, on-demand-resources

The third time fate dropped me a challenge with Apple's content hosting, and for this time I have a problem with on-demand resource only on one specific device.

We have an application that is live in store with on-demand resources support. Currently, we are working on the update, where it's necessary to add some content to be loaded using on-demand resources. After adding resources and uploading build to ITC I can see all assets packs. After testing on-demand resources downloading at iPhone 6s and three iPhones 8 I discovered that on-demand resources downloading don't work at one iPhone 8 at all. Prefetched tags, as well as regular ones, returns an error, and I can see that something went wrong.

The only difference between iPhone 6s, two iPhones 8 and other one iPhone 8 is the last one is currently in Australia. Can on-demand resources downloading depends on locale? If so, why it is happening if the application is available for all over the world?

Did anyone have a similar issue? Thanks.

Comment: I do experience similar issue. Haven't tested it that much. But for some devices ODRs are available while for others they are not.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue on my iPhone 8(iOS version 12.1.4). When I run the on-demand resources, The resource file always shows not downloaded.

I reset my device 
Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset all settings.

It will take 2 mins to reset. After that, I connect my wifi and tried. Now on-demand resources are working fine.

This may help you.

Thanks

Comment: This will reset Apple Pay cards. I dont think it may help anyway.